# How many polycount for smartphone hardware starting from 2015?

Tags: graphics, mobile

I already know that the answer is "depends". Depend if the hardware is low-mid or high hend. 
So, I try to re-formulate: is 100K concurrent polycount in a 3d game for smartphone too much ? 
How many is it a good compromise ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

CPU, GPU capabilities, and screen resolution varies too much, even 2015 onward.

And then it still depends on triangle shape, occlusion, OS version, texture types, size, quantities, vertex and fragment shaders and so on...

You need to buy (or borrow) phones and test your game on specific models and then hope for the best.

Comment: instead of "hope for the best" I'd suggest "adjust your game &/or platform requirements accordingly"

Comment: You can't realistically test every cell phone out there. There are "quad core" 2x400Mhz+2x100Mhz phones. Phones with ~200Mhz single-core GPUs with a 4K screen resolution that can barely draw their home screen. Updates, custom OS versions, and drivers that break everything... All of which generates many upset customers and bad ratings, out of one's control. "Hope for the best" is a realistic expectation.